# Select distinct DateTime properties from List<IDictionary<string,object>> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dynamic, expandoobject

I have a method that returns `List<IDictionary<string,object>>`.

The objects for the dictionary are created using `ExpandoObject` and then added to the list with foreach loop. Here is the example of such object:

```
var dataItem = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
dataItem["String Property 1"] = "String Value 1";
dataItem["String Property 2"] = "String Value 2";
dataItem["DateTime Property 1"] = "DateTime Value 1";
dataItem["DateTime Property 2"] = "DateTime Value 2";
```

From what the method returns, I need to select distinct values of the "DateTime Property 1", but only for date part of it. So, I'm trying to do the following:

```
var unique = GetData().Select(s => s["DateTime Property 1"].ToShortDateString()).Distinct();
```

But it says that there is no such method as `ToShortDateString()`:

> IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for
>   'ToShortDateString' and no extension method 'ToShortDateString'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be
>   found.

Why is the `object` in the dictionary not converted to `DateTime` type automatically when property is assigned a `DateTime` value? When I use `dynamic` everywhere instead of `object`, everything works fine.

How do I make it work when using `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns `List<IDictionary<string,object>>`, so when you access an item within the `Dictionary`, the compiler will treat it as an `object` and so will detect that there is no method `ToShortDateString` defined on it.

If your method instead returns `List<dynamic>` and you access an element as a `dynamic`, the compiler will not check whether or not `ToShortDateString` exists, and so you will get no errors.

If you *know* `s["DateTime Property 1"]` is a `DateTime`, then you can simply cast it

```
((DateTime)s["DateTime Property 1"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Alternatively, you can call `ToString` then parse the result

```
DateTime.Parse(s["DateTime Property 1"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Yes, "DateTime Property 1" is of type `DateTime`. It's calculated by `DateTimeOffset.Parse(JTokenValue.ToString()).DateTime` within a method mentioned above.
Trying to cast `DateTime` did not help: the error about missing `ToShortDateString()` method still remains.
Calling `ToString()` prior to `ToShortDateString()` does not work as `ToShortDateString()` expects `DateTime` as an argument, not a `string` (the error about that appears).

Comment: can you include the code you used to cast to `DateTime`?

Comment: `var unique = GetData().Select(s => (DateTime)s["DateTime Property 1"].ToShortDateString()).Distinct();`

Comment: You're missing brackets, `var unique = GetData().Select(s => ((DateTime)s["DateTime Property 1"]).ToShortDateString()).Distinct();` should work